# Using @parameter as name for new table

Tags: t-sql

I want to make a backup of a table each time I run a stored procedure and want to dynamically add a date to the table name. I'm trying to use the code below but it doesn't work. I'm sure there are better ways to do it.

Tried:

```sql
DECLARE @Currentdate varchar(8) =  FORMAT (getdate(), 'yyyyMMdd') 

DECLARE @filename varchar(500) = 'dbo.table_name_'+@currentdate+''

Select * into @filename from dbo.table_name
```

Yet I get a syntax error for the `select * into` statement line.

> Incorrect syntax near '@filename'.

Comment: In truth, however, it seems that if you need to retain a history of that table, you should perhaps look into something like a temporal table.

Comment: Nothing is more aggravating than opening a production database and seeing 10 copies of a table with a date suffix. Rethink your backup strategy.